# StateHasChanged() does not reload page

Tags: refresh, blazor

**Issue:**

As mentioned in Title, StateHasChanged does not re-render the page

**Objective:**

I want to Refresh the page when a button is clicked

**Current Code**

```
<button @onclick="CreatePlayer">Create User</button>


@functions {
string username;

[CascadingParameter]
Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }

async Task CreatePlayer()
{
    var authState = await authenticationStateTask;
    var user = authState.User;
    var player = await PlayerData.GetByEmail(user.Identity.Name);

    if (player == null)
    {
        player = new Player()
        {
            Email = user.Identity.Name,
            UserName = username
        };

        await PlayerData.Create(player);
    }

    await Task.Delay(50);
    StateHasChanged();

}
}
```

Comment: `StateHasChanged` just inform the component that something changes in is state, that doesn't rerender it. The component choose by itself if it has to rerender or not. You can override `ShouldRender` to force the component to rerender on state changed.

Comment: You shouldn't have to override ShouldRender, it returns true by default.

https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/16119#issuecomment-758657222

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the one hand, you tell the compiler that she should create an event handler for the *click* event, named CreatePlayer: `@onclick="CreatePlayer` . This attribute compiler directive, behind the scenes, creates an `EventCallback<Task>` handler for you, the implication of which is that you do not need to use StateHasChanged in your code  at all, as this method ( StateHasChanged ) is automatically called after UI events take place.

On the other hand, you tell the compiler that the type of the button should be set to "submit". This is wrong of course... You can't have it both. Setting the type attribute to "submit", normally submit form data to the server, but In Blazor it is prevented to work that way by code in the JavaScript portion of Blazor. Do you want to submit a form data to the server ? Always recall Blazor is an SPA Application. No submit ?

Your code should be:

```
<button @onclick="CreatePlayer" >Create User</button>
```

Just for the records, ordinarily you should inject the `AuthenticationStateProvider` object into your components, like this:

```
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider
```

and then retrieve the AuthenticationState object. This is how your code may be rewritten:

```
var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = authState.User;
```

Comment: Hi @enet, thank you for the response, however, the `submit` was an attempt to make make it refresh when the original way did not work. I did try the other one. Secondly, AuthenticationStateProvider is injected. I just inject it in the _imports. Lastlythe shorthand works fine - I'm able to retrieve the user without issues. I don't see how it helps with the issue of refreshing the page.

Comment: First off, you should remove the call to StateHasChanged from your code, even if it 'solves' your problem, as this method is called automatically with UI events. We are dealing with software, not with miracles, and wouldn't want to introduce  superfluous code. More code, more bugs... Now tell me,  did you verify that a player object is created ? Is the call to PlayerData.Create executed properly ?Seeing all the code is a sure way to help you with the problem.

Comment: hi @enet, yes the code executed properly. It went all the way to the DB and I am able to retrieve it when necessary. Since this is only a small practice project I don't mind sharing it: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1a6Jzi3JJEJgqYDsj1JY_QlbWtVeHzklz

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record, I add my comment in an answer :

`StateHasChanged` just inform the component that something changes in is state, that doesn't rerender it. The component choose by itself if it has to rerender or not. You can override `ShouldRender` to force the component to rerender on state changed.

```cs
@code {
    bool _forceRerender;

    async Task CreatePlayer()
    {
        var authState = await authenticationStateTask;
        var user = authState.User;
        var player = await PlayerData.GetByEmail(user.Identity.Name);

        if (player == null)
        {
            player = new Player()
            {
                Email = user.Identity.Name,
                UserName = username
            };

            await PlayerData.Create(player);
        }

        _forceRerender = true;
        StateHasChanged();

    }

    protected override bool ShouldRender()
    {
        if (_forceRerender)
        {
            _forceRerender = false;
            return true;
        }
        return base.ShouldRender();
    }
}
```